# Filter all values before max value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am reasonably perplexed on how to properly do the following. I know it is probably simple but I can't quite figure it out.

Say I have data collected by an instrument that is raised and lowered into the water. Complimentary to the data, a depth reading is taken. Say I am only interested in the data on the way **down** and would like to filter out all the data from the way up. More explicitly I'd like to filter for depth readings **before** the lowest value of `depth`. One small catch is that often the data has a couple depth values that go up slightly before continuing down to the deepest point. So it isn't a pure ascending/descending issue.  Ideally using a `dplyr` approach (or something that work well with `dplyr`) because i have groups in the data. Here is some dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(depth=c(1:6,5,7:10,10.5:1), x=rnorm(21), Group="x")
df2 <- data.frame(depth=c(1:6,5,7:10,10.5:1), x=rnorm(21), Group="y")
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

I keep getting stuck as I am easily able to find the deepest value:

```
df %>% mutate(depth==max(depth))
```

I can also find (using @Marc's answer) the depth for one group:

```
df %>%
  filter(Group=="x") %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  filter(rowname %in% c(seq(which.max(depth))))
```

However, when I try adding a `group_by` statement I still only get the desired result from the first group:

```
df %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(rowname %in% c(seq(which.max(depth))))
```

I didn't expect `group_by` to work with filter but I don't know how to sub for rownames without using filter here. Any ideas here?

Comment: @Psidom - As I said above, it is not strictly an ascending/ descending pattern that I need to match.

Comment: Does @Marc's answer give you what you need?

Comment: @Psidom Not exactly. I haven't quite figured out how to apply this in a `dplyr`-like approach.

Comment: Do you have to use `dplyr`? and which part is not correct with Marc's answer?

Comment: I tried to keep my example simple but my actual application is to do thing exercise by groups. So find all values above the lowest point within a group specified by a factor. So Marc's answer isn't exactly incorrect. I just don't know how to apply the row number approach within `dplyr` so that I can make use of `group_by`

Comment: @Psidom : added a `dplyr` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't seem to come up with a `dplyr` solution for the problem, but the `data.table` alternative works:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, head(.SD, which.max(depth)), by = Group]  
# say the factor is some grouping variable you are trying to apply

    Group depth           x
 1:     x   1.0 -0.22907469
 2:     x   2.0  0.15284187
 3:     x   3.0  1.99289070
 4:     x   4.0 -0.80802497
 5:     x   5.0  0.41455226
 6:     x   6.0  0.39673474
 7:     x   5.0 -0.35179347
 8:     x   7.0 -0.18892176
 9:     x   8.0  2.97448709
10:     x   9.0 -0.14464747
11:     x  10.0  0.99434061
12:     x  10.5 -0.64831649
13:     y   1.0  1.10262757
14:     y   2.0 -0.64630288
15:     y   3.0  0.43909555
16:     y   4.0 -0.00575027
17:     y   5.0 -0.81374528
18:     y   6.0 -0.45948930
19:     y   5.0  0.03333462
20:     y   7.0  0.31111807
21:     y   8.0  1.64502251
22:     y   9.0  0.97451275
23:     y  10.0  1.12403518
24:     y  10.5  1.21710311
    Group depth           x
```

Sticking to `dplyr`, you can create a new `id` variable to label the rows for each group individually and then filter based on `which.max`:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(id = seq_len(n())) %>% filter(id <= which.max(depth))
```

Comment: I've revised my question. I've gotten a bit closer thanks to you and Marc but I'm still not quite there.

Comment: Added a `dplyr` solution to the answer. The problem is that when you add row names using `dplyr`, it is not added by groups so the solution doesn't work. You can add an `id` variable individually for each group and then subset based on that.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(between(row_number(),1,which.max(depth)))
```

Comment: Good answer. It seems that `row_number()` here is by group.

Comment: +1 This answer works, but please note that the filter function here is vulnerable to how you have sorted your data, since it works on row_number. A simple precautionary step to avoid problems could be to sort the data on a variable that indicates the time of measure(not included in OP´s dummy data).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
df[seq(which.max(df$depth)),]
```